# How to addsong in User class using Playlist arrays?

Tags: java

addSong(title:String,filePath: String, artist:String):int 
adds the song to the play list and returns 0 if added and –1 if the song can not be added because the list is full.

*** I keep on getting errors like method addsong(String, String, String) is not applicable for agrument int and also the getArtist method is not defined. How do I go upon it? Any suggestions or solutions to make it work?

PLaylist Class:

```
public class Playlist {
//Instance Variables
private int numOfSongs;
private Songs[] songList;

// Constructors
public Playlist(int maxNumofSongs){
    this.numOfSongs = 0;
    this.songList = new Songs[maxNumofSongs];
}
//Getters 
    public Songs[] getSongList(){
        return songList;
    }
//Methods
public void addSong(String title, String filePath, String artist){
    Songs p = new Songs(title, filePath, artist);
    addSong(p);
}
public void addSong(Songs p){
    songList[this.numOfSongs] = p;
    this.numOfSongs++;
}
public Songs getSong(int pos){
    if (pos <= this.songList.length)
        return this.songList[pos];
    else
        return null;
}
public int getSongByTitle(String title){
    int pos = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.numOfSongs; i++)
        if (this.songList[i].getTitle() == title)
            pos = i;

    return pos;
}
public String toString(){
    String playlistDesc = "";
    playlistDesc += "Number of Songs added in Playlist: "+ numOfSongs;
    return playlistDesc;
}
```

}

User CLass:

```
public class User {
//Instance Variables
private String name;
private String email;
private Playlist favoriteSongs;
Songs[] songs = this.favoriteSongs.getSongList();

//Constructors
public User(String name, String email, Playlist favoriteSongs){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.favoriteSongs = favoriteSongs;
}
public User(String name, String email){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
//Setters
public void setPlayList(Playlist list){
    this.favoriteSongs = list;
}
//Get song title by inputting the position in the playlist array
public String getSongTitle(int pos){
    if (pos < songs.length){
        Songs s = songs[pos];
    //you can then get the title of the song using
        s.getTitle();
    }
    return songs[pos].getTitle();
}
//Add new song to the playlist
public int addSong(String title, String filePath, String artist){
    for(int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
        if (addSong(i) == songs[i].getTitle().getArtist()){ // or what ever you want to compare
            return 0;
          }
          // if you do not found any thing
        return -1;
    }   
    }
//Counts how many songs with the same artist
public int artistSongCount(String artist){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < songs.length; i++)
        if (this.songs[i].getArtist() == artist)
            count++;

    return count;
}
//Print out details of user
public String toString(){
    String userOutput = "";
    userOutput += "Name: "+ name;
    userOutput += "Email: "+ email;
    return userOutput;
}
```

}

Comment: In `User.addSong()` do `if(addSong(songs[i]) == ...`. You're doing `if(addSong(i) == ...` . Also,  not to sound condescending, but you should really learn how to debug since it's an essential programming skill and bugs like the above are some of the easiest to find as the compiler directly points you to them.

Comment: you are calling add song and passing it an int.... and in your question you say add song takes 3 strings, just look at your code more

Comment: It still shows the same error. We haven't learn to use debug yet.

Comment: Been looking for my code for 3 straight days and haven't figure it out.